# How to redirect all child directories to a single directories - over 240,000 directories to re-point

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So this maybe simple so sorry if its obvious, and I've search for the answer already but not real answer came out.

I've just taken over a new site, and it has a game on it which was made in Flash 4.1 so its been taken off now. But each users results had a URL so they could share it, i.e.

/games/thegame/users/*#useridnumber#*/

Now Google is picking up a seriously vast amount of 404 errors because all of those user results have gone - and I mean big, like over 240,000 directories were there.

So simply, how can I redirect all sub directories of "/games/thegame/" to one folder of "/games/newversion/"

I've tried this, but it doesn't have any result:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /games/thegame/*(.*) /games/newversion//$1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `RewriteRule ^games/thegame(/*) /games/newversion/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect at all!